# Old reference of a reference assembly copying issue

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm having an old well known problem, but the regular solution isn't working.

I have a console app. It references a class library. The class library references a nuget package which has WindowsAzure.Storage as a dependency (so the class library ends up with references to both WindowsAzure.Storage and the other nuget package). The code in my class library only references the nuget package's dll, not the WindowsAzure.Storage dll. So, as expected, all the dlls end up in the bin directory for the class library, but only the main nuget package dll and my class library dll end up in the bin directory for my console app.

Normal solution is simply to add a line of code to my class library that references the WindowsAzure.Storage dll. But I tried

```
var t = typeof(WindowsStorage.Storage.....)
```

And the WindowsAzure.Storage dll still wasn't copied to the console app bin directory.

None of the referenced dlls are in the GAC and all are marked as private references in the csproj files.

What's up?

Comment: Why can'tyou reference the WindowsAzure.Storage.dll in your console app and be done with it or add that nuget package to your console app?

Comment: I can, but that's not the point. The truth is I have three console apps...and I don't want to have to manage the second reference in three extra places, especially considering what a mess of a package manager nuget is

Comment: Are you adding a reference to your class library as a project reference inside the console app?

Comment: Yes, structure is Console App references Class Library references (NServiceBus.Azure and WindowsAzure.Storage). Both NServiceBus.Azure and WindowsAzure.Storage are copied to bin directory of Class Library...but only NServiceBus.Azure is in the bin directory of the Console App....EVEN THOUGH I added the explicit code reference using typeof(...) in the Class Library

Comment: Make sure that the CopyLocal property is set to true on the WindowsAzure.Storage reference in your Class Library and rebuild all. Does that work?

Comment: It is (and all references are marked as Private in the csproj files), but it still doesn't copy

Comment: This could be by design...I don't know. Think of how many levels of recursion would be needed to support every scenario. I have had this happen with 3rd party apps being referenced in a library project that my main project referenced. It seemed that I always had to make a reference to the 3rd party assemblies in my main project, not to build, but to run without error. If you come up with a working solution then let me know. One other thing to check is the build order and that is all I can think of.